# Flutter Error | Failed assertion: line 6728 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true. And/Or Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree

Tags: flutter, dynamic, widget

im pretty new to Flutter and have currently some problems with my own widgets. I have a list of List and im trying to build a widget that shows dynamically the amount of LineCharts in my app. As soon as i implement the widget inside of my widget tree, the app stops working with the following message:

"'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6728 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true."

Maybe one of you can help me. I'm grateful for every tip as I've finished the logic so far. Only the UI doesn't quite work yet. I wish you a happy new year!

This is my Widget

```
Widget createDiagrams(List<MyDiagram> finalList) {
    return
      SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index){
            if (finalList.isEmpty){
              return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Keine Einträge vorhanden'
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              List<FlSpot> currentSpotList = finalList[index].myDiagramList;
              return LineChart(
                LineChartData(
                  lineBarsData: [
                    LineChartBarData(
                      spots: currentSpotList,
                      isCurved: true,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        childCount: finalList.length == 0 ? 1: finalList.length,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is my Widget tree:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Material App ist das Material Design --> Design von Google (Quasi default)
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(60),
                ),
              ),
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              expandedHeight: 160.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'SprintS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        letterSpacing: 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                centerTitle: true,
                background: Image.asset(
                  'images/bike.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            connectButtons(),
            _myPlayWidget,
            test(sprintS),
            createDiagrams(sprintS),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
            ),
            ifPressed(),
            // Hier kannst du weitere Sliver-Widgets hinzufügen, wenn benötigt
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, if I comment out the widget in the tree, the app works again. I suspect it might be due to the widget type or the return value. But the "Dart Analaysis" in Flutter doesn't show me any error.